# Why is an InstanceContextMode.Single service disposing the singleton on Close?

Tags: wcf, singleton, servicehost, objectdisposedexception, instancecontextmode

I have a WCF (4.0) service that is decorated as InstanceContextMode.Single and the class implementing the service is follows a Singleton pattern.

I first create the singleton instance of my service implementation with the Instance attribute. Then I pass this single instance to the constructor of ServiceHost rather than using the constructor with typeof() argument.

I can do Open() on the service, I can then do Close() and all is fine. But apparently on Close() it somehow disposes my singleton (???) because when I try again Open() on the same ServiceHost the ObjectDisposedException is thrown.

My service is hosted with NetTcpBInding in a Windows Form appplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-opening the same ServiceHost is not supported. You need to create a new ServiceHost.

ServiceHost implements the ICommunicationObject state machine. From [Understanding State Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041.aspx):

> When in the Closed state the object has essentially reached the end of
>   the state machine. Once an object transitions from one state to the
>   next, it does not go back to a previous state.